# How to append deleted from array elements by slice method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How to delete elements from start of array and append them into end ?
[image]

```
  const ImageArray = [i1,i2,i3,i4,i5]

  const clickHandler = (index: number) => {
        let start = ImageArray.slice(index)
        let end = ImageArray....
        let result = start.concat(end)
        return result
    }

    {ImageArray.map((image, index) => (
                <div
                    onClick={() => clickHandler(index)}
                    key={index} style={{backgroundImage: 'url('+image+')'}}
                />
            ))}
```

P.S. It's not necessary to use slice method

Comment: Your function returns a result, but your `onClick` attribute ignores the returned value? Do you want `ImageArray` to be mutated? If so, where is that happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With x being the index clicked :

```
const arr = [0,1,2,3,4];
const newArr = [...arr.slice(1), ...arr.slice(0, 1)]
```

Comment: It worked to me without subtracting 1 from index

Comment: As the other commenter pointed out, those `x-1` should just be `x`. By subtracting 1, you're indexing from 1 rather than 0, which is inconsistent with the rest of the language.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
const arr = ['i1','i2','i3','i4','i5']
const clickHandler = i => [...arr.slice(i), ...arr.slice(0, i)]

console.log('i3:', clickHandler(2)) // Clicked: 'i3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is designed to return a new array, but the place where you call the function is not doing anything with the returned value.

I assume you want to *mutate* `ImageArray`. In that case use `splice` to delete the first part, and `push` to append that same part at the end:

```
const clickHandler = (index: number) => {
    ImageArray.push(...ImageArray.splice(0, index));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try splice instead

```
const clickHandler = (index) => ImageArray.push(...ImageArray.splice(0, index))
```

In case if you are working with a state and doesn't want to mutate original array, try to spread ImageArray to make not deep copy of it

```
const clickHandler = (index) => {
   const arrCopy = [...ImageArray];
   arrCopy.push(...arrCopy.splice(0, index));
   return arrCopy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 array.splice(index).concat(array.splice(array.length - index))
```